# Convert Matlab code into Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to convert a image processing program(part of the program below) from Matlab to Simulink and possibly convert the simulink diagram into C code later on.  I have 0 experience in Simulink and was wondering if there's any limitations on the types of matlab program/functions that can be converted and how I would go about doing this.  Thanks.

```
clear all
clc

% Read in an image 1
C1 = imread('cloud1.jpg');
Cloud1 = C1(:,:,1);            % use only one color
%Cloud1 = Cloud1';                  % transpose to get (x,y) instead of (y,x)
Cloud1_xsize = size(Cloud1,2);     % get x size of image
Cloud1_ysize = size(Cloud1,1);     % get y size of image
%figure(3), imshow(Cloud1)         % to plot you need to transpose back to their coordinate system
%hold on

% Read in an image 2
C2 = imread('cloud2.jpg');
Cloud2 = C2(:,:,1);            % use only one color
%Cloud2 = Cloud2';                  % transpose to get (x,y) instead of (y,x)
Cloud2_xsize = size(Cloud2,2);     % get x size of image
Cloud2_ysize = size(Cloud2,1);     % get y size of image
%figure(2), imshow(Cloud2)
%hold on

% show the shift in the initial images several times
num = 0;
for k = 1:4
    num=num+1;
    pause(.5)
    figure(1), h1=imshow(C1)
    xlabel('FIGURE 1')
    F(num) = getframe(gcf);
    %image(F.cdata)
    %colormap(F.colormap)
    pause(0.25)
    figure(1), h2=imshow(C2)
    xlabel('FIGURE 2')
    num=num+1;
    F(num) = getframe(gcf);
    %image(F.cdata)
    %colormap(F.colormap)
end   
% Play the movie twenty times
%movie(F,20)


%%%% Set the template size %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% First calc the number of pixels in the shortest direction of the image (usually y direction)  
MinSize = min(Cloud1_xsize, Cloud1_ysize); % number of pixels in shortest direction
%%% N is the minimum number of boxes in the shorter direction (usually y direction). 
%%% In the shorter axis (usually y)there will be N-2 boxes analyzed. 
%%% This is because the top and bottom boxes are considered too close to the edge to use. 
%%% In the larger direction (usually x) there may be more boxes. 
N = 6;   
EdgeBoxSize = 1;                    % the number of edge boxes along each edge
TempWidth = floor(MinSize / N);     % the pixel width of each template box
TempHeight = TempWidth;              % make the template height and width the same size so corr part works good
%%% Now calculate the exact number of boxes in x and y directions  
%%% This depends on the number of x versus y pixels. 
Nx = floor(Cloud1_xsize/TempWidth);  
Ny = floor(Cloud1_ysize/TempWidth);
```

Comment: You're most likely better off looking into using [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/).

Comment: On a cursory glance, this code contains a fair bit of graphics elements, which cannot (generally) be converted to C code. Also, as far as I know, there's no way to convert MATLAB code into a Simulink model directly. Like Phil suggested, you could try converting the math part of your code into equivalent C. Alternatively, you could look at the MATLAB Function Block (https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/what-is-a-matlab-function-block.html).

Comment: @akamath I think the MATLAB Function Block might be what I'm looking for.  Also if anyone else has any opinions I would love to hear them.